# Change Control size based on its text font size

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms, fonts

I have a Win Form, in which I am changing all the controls text font(Font size, font style etc) during run-time.

So, I am able to get the label to change its fonts and size also. But how to change the fonts of controls and also to resize the controls according to the size of the font.

I have already changing all the controls font and still its not getting reflected in the form after assigning.

So any idea's??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understand your question clearly, you want something like adjust the width and height of the text box in your form based on the text length and size isn't?

If so, create a windows forms and put one text box into the form and add this into your designer form:

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
```

or if you didn't want to add above code into the designer form, just add that into the form's code itself:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);

            textBox1.Width = size.Width;
            textBox1.Height = size.Height;
        }
```

May this answer would help you.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi i tested your code. The font of the text is getting changed. But the size of the textbox is still not getting adjusted.